Using an autorun script to drive a USB drive to a folder in the user folder
I would like to automatically mount my USB drive to a folder in the user directory when I put it in any Windows machine. Is there any way to do this?
The end result should be the exact same as manually mounting it to an NTFS folder through Disk Management.
The use case is a piece of software that I want to use but it saves the absolute file paths and thus breaks when the drive gets a new drive letter. Setting the drive letter to the same one every time isn't a good solution as it can lead to conflicts between drives.

Does the converse work, i.e., make a link in the folder with the name of the location the software uses, and set the link to the USB drive?

@DrMoishePippik That might work with a symlink but even so I don't know how I'd write such a script. I'd try to find out myself but I'd rather ask people with experience so I don't mess up my drives somehow.

Create a bat file and put this code:

' 2> nul
SET "batFilePath=%~f0"
powershell -Command "Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList \"-Command `\"`$batFilePath = \`\"$env:batFilePath\`\"`\";Invoke-Expression (Get-Content `$batFilePath -Raw)\""
exit %errorlevel%
' | Out-Null

# Define the folder where the USB should be mounted
$MountFolder = "UsbDrive"

$DriveLetter = [string]$batFilePath[0]
if (!(Test-Path -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\$MountFolder")) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\$MountFolder"
}

Add-PartitionAccessPath -DriveLetter $DriveLetter -AccessPath "$env:USERPROFILE\$MountFolder"

Change the line:$MountFolder = "UsbDrive" to your desired folder name.
Then when you put in the USB run the file.
To autorun the file you can try to create a 'autorun.inf' but for security reasons its mostly blocked.
To test it add a 'pause' like this:

' 2> nul
SET "batFilePath=%~f0"
powershell -Command "Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList \"-NoExit -Command `\"`$batFilePath = \`\"$env:batFilePath\`\"`\";Invoke-Expression (Get-Content `$batFilePath -Raw)\""
pause
exit %errorlevel%
' | Out-Null

$MountFolder = "UsbDrive"

$DriveLetter = [string]$batFilePath[0]
if (!(Test-Path -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\$MountFolder")) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\$MountFolder"
}

Add-PartitionAccessPath -DriveLetter $DriveLetter -AccessPath "$env:USERPROFILE\$MountFolder"


It doesn't seem to work, I'm not getting a clear error out of it either

Still won't work for me, I'm also not get any errors when using the pause, it doesn't even create the folder so I'm guessing it exists on the first exit in your script

Now the Powershell window says "DiskPart was unable to process the parameters.", folder was created this time

I get "New-PSDrive : When you use the Persist parameter, the root must be a file system location on a remote computer."

Now it's "DiskPart was unable to process the parameters."

That worked! If you could update your original answer with this it should do exactly what I want

Ok, I updated my answer, Tested and works.

Now, after all I saw your comment that a Symbolic Link may be enough for your use case, if so, we don't need this all stuff, you can create a bat file with this 1 line mklink /D "%USERPROFILE%\MyUSBLink" "%~d0" and right click the file and run as administrator, or , if a Junction is enough you don't need admin rights simply put this line mklink /J "%USERPROFILE%\MyUSBLink" "%~d0" and run it.
